# Gradle project sync fail, no toolchains

Tags: android, gradle, android-ndk

Hello I'm getting this error in android studio :

Gradle project sync failed. Basic functionality (editing, debugging) will not work properly

And in messages I get this :

Gradle sync failed: No toolchains found in the NDK toolchains folder for ABI with prefix: arm-linux-androideabi

I've searched for a solution, but I haven't found one.

Hopefully someone from here can help me.

Comment: Well, what's under <android-ndk-path>/toolchains? Is there a toolchain named arm-linux-androideabi-<something>? If not, what version of the NDK are you using and how are you selecting your toolchain?

Answer (score 7):

As MustafaKemal, I canceled an NDK update, and after that I got the Gradle sync error message.

What solved my problem: on Android Studio go to Tools -> Android -> SDK manager -> SDK Tool  and uncheck the Android NDK checkbox, then Apply.

After that, open the item again and check it and apply to reinstall it.

then be patient, it might seem the installation is stuck whilst unzipping a file but after a while, a long while, it finishes.

Answer (score 1):

According the GitHub [post](https://github.com/google/filament/issues/15#issuecomment-416098596), your Android Gradle plugin is looking for mips toolchain which may not exist. Solution is to update the Android Gradle plugin and Gradle version.

Update Android Gradle plugin version in the `app` level `build.gradle` file.

```
buildscript {
...
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
        ...
    }
}
```

Android Gradle plugin will also require Gradle version 4.4 which you may update in `gradle-wrapper.properties`.

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, because I canceled the NDK update, while unzipping because it took to much time... I solved the problem by deleting NDK - bundle folder under
/Users/..../Library/Android/sdk    and re-install it. But it took almost 3-4 hours :(

Answer (score -1):

[image]
**First**

open **build.gradle(module:app)** app file and make following changes in it.

- replace **compile**(if present) with **api** wherever api ref. like: volley, GitHub dependancy.strong text is used and
- replace **compile** (if present) with **implementation** incase of using android libraries like play-services-maps,appcompat-v7 etc.

example:
old way

```
  dependencies {
     testCompile'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
```

Change it to:

```
 dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
```

**Then,**

open **build.gradle (Project: yourproject)** file
* and change the google gms services to the latest

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
```

**Then,**

- Open **gradle-wrapper.properties** file and replace it with following:

> ```
> distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
> distributionPath=wrapper/dists
> distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip
> zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
> zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
> ```

Perform **gradle sync** and then **Rebuild** the project.

Answer (score -2):

Your Android Studio does not include NDK.
You can fix this problem.

**Android Studio  -> Tools -> Android -> SDK manager -> SDK Tool**

**You must install NDK here.**