# No arm-linux-androideabi toolchain found in stripDebugDebugSymbols step

Tags: android, android-ndk

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37565243/errorno-toolchains-found-in-the-ndk-toolchains-folder-for-abi-with-prefix-arm), I get the same error but in a different place:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:stripDebugDebugSymbols'.
> No toolchains found in the NDK toolchains folder for ABI with prefix: arm-linux-androideabi
```

Various other answers suggest clearing build folders, uninstalling and reinstalling the NDK, etc. I've done that many times but still get this error.

The thing I don't understand is that is looking for an `arm-linux-androideabi` toolchain. The contents of my `C:\Users\Tim\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\23.0.7123448\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin` directory are:

```
19/02/2021  14:42         1,424,896 aarch64-linux-android-as.exe
19/02/2021  14:42               182 aarch64-linux-android21-clang
19/02/2021  14:42               186 aarch64-linux-android21-clang++
19/02/2021  14:42               435 aarch64-linux-android21-clang++.cmd
19/02/2021  14:42               431 aarch64-linux-android21-clang.cmd
19/02/2021  14:42               182 aarch64-linux-android22-clang
19/02/2021  14:42               186 aarch64-linux-android22-clang++
19/02/2021  14:42               435 aarch64-linux-android22-clang++.cmd
19/02/2021  14:42               431 aarch64-linux-android22-clang.cmd
19/02/2021  14:42               182 aarch64-linux-android23-clang
19/02/2021  14:42               186 aarch64-linux-android23-clang++
19/02/2021  14:42               435 aarch64-linux-android23-clang++.cmd
19/02/2021  14:42               431 aarch64-linux-android23-clang.cmd
19/02/2021  14:42               182 aarch64-linux-android24-clang
19/02/2021  14:42               186 aarch64-linux-android24-clang++
19/02/2021  14:42               435 aarch64-linux-android24-clang++.cmd
19/02/2021  14:42               431 aarch64-linux-android24-clang.cmd
19/02/2021  14:42               182 aarch64-linux-android26-clang
19/02/2021  14:42               186 aarch64-linux-android26-clang++
19/02/2021  14:42               435 aarch64-linux-android26-clang++.cmd
19/02/2021  14:42               431 aarch64-linux-android26-clang.cmd
19/02/2021  14:42               182 aarch64-linux-android27-clang
19/02/2021  14:42               186 aarch64-linux-android27-clang++
19/02/2021  14:42               435 aarch64-linux-android27-clang++.cmd
19/02/2021  14:42               431 aarch64-linux-android27-clang.cmd
19/02/2021  14:42               182 aarch64-linux-android28-clang
19/02/2021  14:42               186 aarch64-linux-android28-clang++
19/02/2021  14:42               435 aarch64-linux-android28-clang++.cmd
19/02/2021  14:42               431 aarch64-linux-android28-clang.cmd
19/02/2021  14:42               182 aarch64-linux-android29-clang
19/02/2021  14:42               186 aarch64-linux-android29-clang++
19/02/2021  14:42               435 aarch64-linux-android29-clang++.cmd
19/02/2021  14:42               431 aarch64-linux-android29-clang.cmd
19/02/2021  14:42               182 aarch64-linux-android30-clang
19/02/2021  14:42               186 aarch64-linux-android30-clang++
19/02/2021  14:42               435 aarch64-linux-android30-clang++.cmd
19/02/2021  14:42               431 aarch64-linux-android30-clang.cmd
19/02/2021  14:42               182 aarch64-linux-android31-clang
19/02/2021  14:42               186 aarch64-linux-android31-clang++
19/02/2021  14:42               435 aarch64-linux-android31-clang++.cmd
19/02/2021  14:42               431 aarch64-linux-android31-clang.cmd
19/02/2021  14:42         1,354,752 arm-linux-androideabi-as.exe
19/02/2021  14:42               185 armv7a-linux-androideabi16-clang
19/02/2021  14:42               189 armv7a-linux-androideabi16-clang++
19/02/2021  14:42               438 armv7a-linux-androideabi16-clang++.cmd
19/02/2021  14:42               434 armv7a-linux-androideabi16-clang.cmd
19/02/2021  14:42               185 armv7a-linux-androideabi17-clang
19/02/2021  14:42               189 armv7a-linux-androideabi17-clang++
19/02/2021  14:42               438 armv7a-linux-androideabi17-clang++.cmd
19/02/2021  14:42               434 armv7a-linux-androideabi17-clang.cmd
19/02/2021  14:42               185 armv7a-linux-androideabi18-clang
19/02/2021  14:42               189 armv7a-linux-androideabi18-clang++
19/02/2021  14:42               438 armv7a-linux-androideabi18-clang++.cmd
19/02/2021  14:42               434 armv7a-linux-androideabi18-clang.cmd
19/02/2021  14:42               185 armv7a-linux-androideabi19-clang
19/02/2021  14:42               189 armv7a-linux-androideabi19-clang++
19/02/2021  14:42               438 armv7a-linux-androideabi19-clang++.cmd
19/02/2021  14:42               434 armv7a-linux-androideabi19-clang.cmd
19/02/2021  14:42               185 armv7a-linux-androideabi21-clang
19/02/2021  14:42               189 armv7a-linux-androideabi21-clang++
19/02/2021  14:42               438 armv7a-linux-androideabi21-clang++.cmd
19/02/2021  14:42               434 armv7a-linux-androideabi21-clang.cmd
19/02/2021  14:42               185 armv7a-linux-androideabi22-clang
19/02/2021  14:42               189 armv7a-linux-androideabi22-clang++
19/02/2021  14:42               438 armv7a-linux-androideabi22-clang++.cmd
19/02/2021  14:42               434 armv7a-linux-androideabi22-clang.cmd
19/02/2021  14:42               185 armv7a-linux-androideabi23-clang
19/02/2021  14:42               189 armv7a-linux-androideabi23-clang++
19/02/2021  14:42               438 armv7a-linux-androideabi23-clang++.cmd
19/02/2021  14:42               434 armv7a-linux-androideabi23-clang.cmd
19/02/2021  14:42               185 armv7a-linux-androideabi24-clang
19/02/2021  14:42               189 armv7a-linux-androideabi24-clang++
19/02/2021  14:42               438 armv7a-linux-androideabi24-clang++.cmd
19/02/2021  14:42               434 armv7a-linux-androideabi24-clang.cmd
19/02/2021  14:42               185 armv7a-linux-androideabi26-clang
19/02/2021  14:42               189 armv7a-linux-androideabi26-clang++
19/02/2021  14:42               438 armv7a-linux-androideabi26-clang++.cmd
19/02/2021  14:42               434 armv7a-linux-androideabi26-clang.cmd
19/02/2021  14:42               185 armv7a-linux-androideabi27-clang
19/02/2021  14:42               189 armv7a-linux-androideabi27-clang++
19/02/2021  14:42               438 armv7a-linux-androideabi27-clang++.cmd
19/02/2021  14:42               434 armv7a-linux-androideabi27-clang.cmd
19/02/2021  14:42               185 armv7a-linux-androideabi28-clang
19/02/2021  14:42               189 armv7a-linux-androideabi28-clang++
19/02/2021  14:42               438 armv7a-linux-androideabi28-clang++.cmd
19/02/2021  14:42               434 armv7a-linux-androideabi28-clang.cmd
19/02/2021  14:42               185 armv7a-linux-androideabi29-clang
19/02/2021  14:42               189 armv7a-linux-androideabi29-clang++
19/02/2021  14:42               438 armv7a-linux-androideabi29-clang++.cmd
19/02/2021  14:42               434 armv7a-linux-androideabi29-clang.cmd
19/02/2021  14:42               185 armv7a-linux-androideabi30-clang
19/02/2021  14:42               189 armv7a-linux-androideabi30-clang++
19/02/2021  14:42               438 armv7a-linux-androideabi30-clang++.cmd
19/02/2021  14:42               434 armv7a-linux-androideabi30-clang.cmd
19/02/2021  14:42               185 armv7a-linux-androideabi31-clang
19/02/2021  14:42               189 armv7a-linux-androideabi31-clang++
19/02/2021  14:42               438 armv7a-linux-androideabi31-clang++.cmd
19/02/2021  14:42               434 armv7a-linux-androideabi31-clang.cmd
19/02/2021  14:42        86,267,392 clang++.exe
19/02/2021  14:42        68,813,312 clang-check.exe
19/02/2021  14:42        86,267,392 clang-cl.exe
19/02/2021  14:42         5,969,408 clang-format.exe
19/02/2021  14:42        51,542,016 clang-tidy.exe
19/02/2021  14:42        86,267,392 clang.exe
19/02/2021  14:42        35,720,192 dsymutil.exe
19/02/2021  14:42            21,426 git-clang-format
19/02/2021  14:42         1,792,512 i686-linux-android-as.exe
19/02/2021  14:42               194 i686-linux-android16-clang
19/02/2021  14:42               198 i686-linux-android16-clang++
19/02/2021  14:42               447 i686-linux-android16-clang++.cmd
19/02/2021  14:42               443 i686-linux-android16-clang.cmd
19/02/2021  14:42               194 i686-linux-android17-clang
19/02/2021  14:42               198 i686-linux-android17-clang++
19/02/2021  14:42               447 i686-linux-android17-clang++.cmd
19/02/2021  14:42               443 i686-linux-android17-clang.cmd
19/02/2021  14:42               194 i686-linux-android18-clang
19/02/2021  14:42               198 i686-linux-android18-clang++
19/02/2021  14:42               447 i686-linux-android18-clang++.cmd
19/02/2021  14:42               443 i686-linux-android18-clang.cmd
19/02/2021  14:42               194 i686-linux-android19-clang
19/02/2021  14:42               198 i686-linux-android19-clang++
19/02/2021  14:42               447 i686-linux-android19-clang++.cmd
19/02/2021  14:42               443 i686-linux-android19-clang.cmd
19/02/2021  14:42               194 i686-linux-android21-clang
19/02/2021  14:42               198 i686-linux-android21-clang++
19/02/2021  14:42               447 i686-linux-android21-clang++.cmd
19/02/2021  14:42               443 i686-linux-android21-clang.cmd
19/02/2021  14:42               194 i686-linux-android22-clang
19/02/2021  14:42               198 i686-linux-android22-clang++
19/02/2021  14:42               447 i686-linux-android22-clang++.cmd
19/02/2021  14:42               443 i686-linux-android22-clang.cmd
19/02/2021  14:42               194 i686-linux-android23-clang
19/02/2021  14:42               198 i686-linux-android23-clang++
19/02/2021  14:42               447 i686-linux-android23-clang++.cmd
19/02/2021  14:42               443 i686-linux-android23-clang.cmd
19/02/2021  14:42               179 i686-linux-android24-clang
19/02/2021  14:42               183 i686-linux-android24-clang++
19/02/2021  14:42               432 i686-linux-android24-clang++.cmd
19/02/2021  14:42               428 i686-linux-android24-clang.cmd
19/02/2021  14:42               179 i686-linux-android26-clang
19/02/2021  14:42               183 i686-linux-android26-clang++
19/02/2021  14:42               432 i686-linux-android26-clang++.cmd
19/02/2021  14:42               428 i686-linux-android26-clang.cmd
19/02/2021  14:42               179 i686-linux-android27-clang
19/02/2021  14:42               183 i686-linux-android27-clang++
19/02/2021  14:42               432 i686-linux-android27-clang++.cmd
19/02/2021  14:42               428 i686-linux-android27-clang.cmd
19/02/2021  14:42               179 i686-linux-android28-clang
19/02/2021  14:42               183 i686-linux-android28-clang++
19/02/2021  14:42               432 i686-linux-android28-clang++.cmd
19/02/2021  14:42               428 i686-linux-android28-clang.cmd
19/02/2021  14:42               179 i686-linux-android29-clang
19/02/2021  14:42               183 i686-linux-android29-clang++
19/02/2021  14:42               432 i686-linux-android29-clang++.cmd
19/02/2021  14:42               428 i686-linux-android29-clang.cmd
19/02/2021  14:42               179 i686-linux-android30-clang
19/02/2021  14:42               183 i686-linux-android30-clang++
19/02/2021  14:42               432 i686-linux-android30-clang++.cmd
19/02/2021  14:42               428 i686-linux-android30-clang.cmd
19/02/2021  14:42               179 i686-linux-android31-clang
19/02/2021  14:42               183 i686-linux-android31-clang++
19/02/2021  14:42               432 i686-linux-android31-clang++.cmd
19/02/2021  14:42               428 i686-linux-android31-clang.cmd
19/02/2021  14:42        51,307,008 ld.exe
19/02/2021  14:42        51,307,008 ld.lld.exe
19/02/2021  14:42        87,413,760 liblldb.dll
19/02/2021  14:42           572,009 libwinpthread-1.dll
19/02/2021  14:42         1,579,520 libxml2.dll
19/02/2021  14:42         1,362,432 lldb-argdumper.exe
19/02/2021  14:42                97 lldb.cmd
19/02/2021  14:42         1,415,680 lldb.exe
19/02/2021  14:42         8,331,776 llvm-addr2line.exe
19/02/2021  14:42        13,378,048 llvm-ar.exe
19/02/2021  14:42         9,076,736 llvm-as.exe
19/02/2021  14:42        16,937,984 llvm-cfi-verify.exe
19/02/2021  14:42         1,395,712 llvm-config.exe
19/02/2021  14:42         7,606,784 llvm-cov.exe
19/02/2021  14:42         4,737,536 llvm-dis.exe
19/02/2021  14:42        11,976,192 llvm-dwarfdump.exe
19/02/2021  14:42        13,378,048 llvm-lib.exe
19/02/2021  14:42         9,990,656 llvm-link.exe
19/02/2021  14:42         8,714,752 llvm-modextract.exe
19/02/2021  14:42        13,467,648 llvm-nm.exe
19/02/2021  14:42         7,344,640 llvm-objcopy.exe
19/02/2021  14:42        15,574,016 llvm-objdump.exe
19/02/2021  14:42         4,390,912 llvm-profdata.exe
19/02/2021  14:42        13,378,048 llvm-ranlib.exe
19/02/2021  14:42         1,523,200 llvm-rc.exe
19/02/2021  14:42         9,350,656 llvm-readelf.exe
19/02/2021  14:42         9,350,656 llvm-readobj.exe
19/02/2021  14:42         6,747,648 llvm-size.exe
19/02/2021  14:42         1,349,120 llvm-strings.exe
19/02/2021  14:42         7,344,640 llvm-strip.exe
19/02/2021  14:42         8,331,776 llvm-symbolizer.exe
19/02/2021  14:42         4,934,144 python38.dll
19/02/2021  14:42        15,120,896 sancov.exe
19/02/2021  14:42         8,294,912 sanstats.exe
19/02/2021  14:42         1,792,512 x86_64-linux-android-as.exe
19/02/2021  14:42               181 x86_64-linux-android21-clang
19/02/2021  14:42               185 x86_64-linux-android21-clang++
19/02/2021  14:42               434 x86_64-linux-android21-clang++.cmd
19/02/2021  14:42               430 x86_64-linux-android21-clang.cmd
19/02/2021  14:42               181 x86_64-linux-android22-clang
19/02/2021  14:42               185 x86_64-linux-android22-clang++
19/02/2021  14:42               434 x86_64-linux-android22-clang++.cmd
19/02/2021  14:42               430 x86_64-linux-android22-clang.cmd
19/02/2021  14:42               181 x86_64-linux-android23-clang
19/02/2021  14:42               185 x86_64-linux-android23-clang++
19/02/2021  14:42               434 x86_64-linux-android23-clang++.cmd
19/02/2021  14:42               430 x86_64-linux-android23-clang.cmd
19/02/2021  14:42               181 x86_64-linux-android24-clang
19/02/2021  14:42               185 x86_64-linux-android24-clang++
19/02/2021  14:42               434 x86_64-linux-android24-clang++.cmd
19/02/2021  14:42               430 x86_64-linux-android24-clang.cmd
19/02/2021  14:42               181 x86_64-linux-android26-clang
19/02/2021  14:42               185 x86_64-linux-android26-clang++
19/02/2021  14:42               434 x86_64-linux-android26-clang++.cmd
19/02/2021  14:42               430 x86_64-linux-android26-clang.cmd
19/02/2021  14:42               181 x86_64-linux-android27-clang
19/02/2021  14:42               185 x86_64-linux-android27-clang++
19/02/2021  14:42               434 x86_64-linux-android27-clang++.cmd
19/02/2021  14:42               430 x86_64-linux-android27-clang.cmd
19/02/2021  14:42               181 x86_64-linux-android28-clang
19/02/2021  14:42               185 x86_64-linux-android28-clang++
19/02/2021  14:42               434 x86_64-linux-android28-clang++.cmd
19/02/2021  14:42               430 x86_64-linux-android28-clang.cmd
19/02/2021  14:42               181 x86_64-linux-android29-clang
19/02/2021  14:42               185 x86_64-linux-android29-clang++
19/02/2021  14:42               434 x86_64-linux-android29-clang++.cmd
19/02/2021  14:42               430 x86_64-linux-android29-clang.cmd
19/02/2021  14:42               181 x86_64-linux-android30-clang
19/02/2021  14:42               185 x86_64-linux-android30-clang++
19/02/2021  14:42               434 x86_64-linux-android30-clang++.cmd
19/02/2021  14:42               430 x86_64-linux-android30-clang.cmd
19/02/2021  14:42               181 x86_64-linux-android31-clang
19/02/2021  14:42               185 x86_64-linux-android31-clang++
19/02/2021  14:42               434 x86_64-linux-android31-clang++.cmd
19/02/2021  14:42               430 x86_64-linux-android31-clang.cmd
```

As you can see, the only `arm-linux-androideabi` program is `arm-linux-androideabi-as.exe` which seems a bit weird. I even tried adding this to my `app/build.gradle` as suggested [on this page](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis).

```
        ndk {
            abiFilters 'arm64-v8a'
        }
```

Which I think means it should only build using the `armv7a-linux-androideabi29` toolchain. `arm-linux-androideabi` isn't even mentioned on [the list of target triples](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/other_build_systems).

What is going on here?

Comment: The page you linked to says: _"For 32-bit ARM, the compiler is prefixed with armv7a-linux-androideabi, but the binutils tools are prefixed with arm-linux-androideabi "_. `as` is a part of binutils, `clang` is not.

Comment: As for `'arm64-v8a'`, that would correspond to the `aarch64` toolchain, not `armv7a`.

Comment: The [changelog](https://github.com/android/ndk/wiki/Changelog-r23) for NDK r23 says: _"GNU binutils, excluding the GNU Assembler (GAS), has been removed. GAS will be removed in the next release"_. Presumably the `stripDebugSymbols` rule is looking for `arm-linux-androideabi-strip.exe` (which is a part of binutils) and not finding it. Are you using an old version of the Android Gradle Plugin? If so, maybe try updating it.

Comment: You say you tried uninstalling and re-installing NDK, but if you haven't tried simply uninstalling it *without* reinstalling, my answer may work for you.  It did for me with exactly the same error message.

Comment: @Michael Aha! I kind of assumed that creating a new Flutter project would give you the latest version. Apparently not. It gave me version 3.5.0. I upgraded it to the latest (4.1.2). It then gives you some error about `distributionUrl` and the instructions to fix it (why is that even necessary if it already knows the correct value? Gradle smh.). After that it worked!

Comment: Given that changelog I presume installing NDK r22 would also work but I didn't try it.

Answer (score 11):

According to [this comment](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/76393#issuecomment-784014307) in the flutter repository issues you need to select a < 20 NDK  version.

[image]

Comment: this solved the issue for me too!!!. thanks

Answer (score 8):

I have no idea how the build process works, really, but I had the same error you did and fixed it by going to:

Tools\SDK Manager\Android SDK\

Then uncheck "Hide obsolete packages"

Then (hopefully) you see this conspicuous item at the the end of the list:

(this is a screenshot AFTER I uninstalled it)

[image]

If you uncheck it and apply, that's what worked for me.

I'm guessing the latest NDK update had a bug and this effectively reverses the latest update.  What do you think?  Talk amongst yourselves.  Coffee talk.