# Bitbucket Pipelines: No toolchains found in the NDK toolchains folder for ABI with prefix: aarch64-linux-android

Tags: android, docker, android-ndk, dockerfile, bitbucket-pipelines

I am totally new to CI with [Bitbucket Pipelines](https://bitbucket.org/product/features/pipelines) and was currently setting up pipeline with the help of [this article](https://medium.com/@_tiwiz/building-android-with-bitbucket-pipelines-83cd62dbde33). My builds are failing due to this error

> "No toolchains found in the NDK toolchains folder for ABI with prefix: aarch64-linux-android"

Can anyone help me fixing this?

Comment: If you are using the unmodified Uber's [docker](https://github.com/uber-common/android-build-environment/blob/master/Dockerfile), then you have NDK r12 there. Maybe your project relies on something else.

Comment: try using following method
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54019946/7831470

Answer (score 7):

Today I run into the same issue like you. I also followed the [blog post](https://medium.com/@_tiwiz/building-android-with-bitbucket-pipelines-83cd62dbde33) you mentioned. Whatever. I'm happy to report you: I fixed it and found a "solution"!

The funny part is: The solution so dumb as simple. The only thing you have to do is to `unset` (or remove) the NDK environment variable (or directory).

The magic line is:

```
- unset ANDROID_NDK_HOME
```

Which means that my final `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` looks like:

```
image: uber/android-build-environment:latest

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script:
          - unset ANDROID_NDK_HOME
          - ./ci/accept_android_license.sh
          - ./gradlew :app:testDebugUnitTest
```

**Why does it fix the issue?**

To be honest. I don't know . But I found out that the `uber`s `android-build-environment` [install the NDK](https://github.com/uber-common/android-build-environment/blob/8d56564d073149a6c883b80e93e254ed6c3864f6/Dockerfile#L77) for you.

I found some answers - like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37646019/1231245) - to install the NDK separately again. But I thought about the following: Why the hell should I install/update the NDK if my project doesn't use it? So I tried to remove the NDK folder (which according to the [`Dockerfile`](https://github.com/uber-common/android-build-environment/blob/8d56564d073149a6c883b80e93e254ed6c3864f6/Dockerfile#L86) located at `/usr/local/android-ndk`) and everything works .

**Why `unset`ting then?**

You can't remove the `android-ndk` dir because you don't have permission to do it. But you can delete the content from it. That is the reason why it worked with `rm -rf /usr/local/android-ndk`. But then - with the setting of `ANDROID_NDK_HOME` but without any content in there you got the error message (while building):

```
./gradlew :app:testDebugUnitTest

NDK is missing a "platforms" directory.
If you are using NDK, verify the ndk.dir is set to a valid NDK directory.  It is currently set to /usr/local/android-ndk.
If you are not using NDK, unset the NDK variable from ANDROID_NDK_HOME or local.properties to remove this warning.
```

`unset` the environment variable fix that warning as well.

**Important:**

Obviously that is not the best solution. If your App uses the NDK this solution will not help. To remove some environment variables "from a Docker image" in a `CI` script is also not the best solution. Maybe the image need the variable later (don't know if that is possible in Docker... but you know what I mean ). But it will "temporary" fix the problem and since the `android-build-environment` is unmaintained (not update since a year) anyway I would not put to much effort in fixing the image...

> **Note:** The link to the `uber:android-build-environment` GitHub page refers to a single (currently the last) commit. If someone read that in the future the link is still active and correct but maybe the `master` branch have changed.

Answer (score 4):

```
cd .../AndroidSdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains
ln -s aarch64-linux-android-4.9 mips64el-linux-android-4.9
ln -s arm-linux-androideabi-4.9 mipsel-linux-android-4.9
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

You need to download `android ndk` and install the [standalone toolchain](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/standalone_toolchain.html) similar like this

`$NDK/build/tools/make_standalone_toolchain.py \
    --arch arm --api 21 --install-dir /tmp/my-android-toolchain`

Sometimes you have to create the environmental variable for the toolchain.